# Is there a way to bypass the Power-Shell confirmation(Y/N) prompt?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Is there a way to bypass the PowerShell cmdlet's confirmation prompt (Yes/No) which is not included in the module's function.

Any suggestions or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific function or module in mind that prompts (but doesn't have a `-Confirm` parameter)?

Comment: Yes, the function doesn't have a force/confirmation parameter.

Below is the code for that function
https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit/blob/master/src/AzSK/SVT/SVT.ps1

Comment: _Which_ module doesn't have the expected parameters? Solution will depend highly on whether you're being prompted by a command internally call either `ShouldProcess()` or `ShouldContinue()` - or if it's some custom home-spun confirmation logic

Comment: Looks like the authors of that module implemented their own confirmation prompts, can't be overridden via preference variables unfortunately. Best option is to rewrite the scripts to use `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` instead of their homespun confirmation prompts, then and submit a PR to the github project to fix it upstream

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @VINOD KUMAR You can post an answer to end this question. This will help others who face the similar question.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ECHO Y | powershell` worked fine locally